# WinForm MessageBox replacement with copy and "more detail" option?

Tags: winforms, messagebox

I have seen some apps with a messagebox which allows the user to copy the message and a "more detail" button which when clicked, the messagebox expands to show more information.

Is there a similar free component I can download and use in my .NET apps (preferably with source)? I know I probably can develop one but I just want a ready made one.

Comment: A quick comment: while searching Google for a similar solution, my own question here showed up at Google just after 13 minutes after posting it. That's impressive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet this [Code Project page](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/MessageBoxEx.aspx) will get you headed in the right direction. I've used it myself in the past.

Comment: there are several replacements on that site, just google "MessageBOX replacement".